# How do I launch a URL with credentials from C# in the default web browser

Tags: c#, url

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4. I want to launch a URL with username and password in the system's default web browser. The web page must load without prompting the user for a logon. This cannot be accomplished with a system call because IE no longer supports URLs with "[https://username:password@website.com](https://username%3apassword@website.com)". Is there a way to get around this restriction in code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the login a pop up login, or a login on the webpage?
If it's a login on the webpage you can use the `GetElementById("ID").SetAttribute("value", "YourValueHere");` For your username and password then you can click the button to login the same way only with the `.InvokeMember("click");` method.

Comment: It is a pop up logon before the webpage renders.

Comment: I'm not sure how to exactly do that off the top of my head. You might be able to do something with P/Invoke. Or you could make it so that when you run it, your mouse would click on the textbox, enter the information via code, then click the button with putting your cursor there and invoking a click. That's just one idea though.

Comment: This is mainly an issue I'm having with IE. A URL with the format "https://username:password@website.com" will work in chrome. The login popup is the standard one that every browser has a version, see the link. I have found examples but nothing that actually pops up the browser.


http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;[LN];834489